# MySQL Column Constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a table which will allow to insert values into a column with values greater than 10.
When I tried in net, they suggested to create table in following way.

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `UID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ID` int(11) default NULL,
  CHECK (ID > 10),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`UID`)
);

And when I try to insert an entry with values less than 10, still values are getting inserted.

I can use Before trigger on the table to restrict insertion of values less than 10.
But I wanted other approach which satisfies this condition.

I am using MySQL server 5.0.24

Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

According to MySQL doc: 
"The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any other approach to have check on the column other than trigger.

Comment: Not at a the moment. It's the only solution so far.